# Find Rows And Delete it - Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
Example dataframe:
      name stuff  floats  ints
0     Mike     a     1.0     1
1     Joey     d     2.2     3
2  Zendaya     c     NaN     8
3     John     a     1.0     1
4  Abruzzi     d     NaN     3
```

I have 'to_delete' list :

```
[['Abruzzi', 'd', pd.NA, 3], ['Mike', 'a', 1.0, 1]]
```

How can i remove data in the dataframe based on the 'to_delete' list?
What pandas method suit this?

So i will get new dataframe like:

```
      name stuff  floats  ints
1     Joey     d     2.2     3
2  Zendaya     c     NaN     8
3     John     a     1.0     1
```

Thanks,

*im new to pandas

Comment: you can just .query or use loc, or or iloc, based on some condition.

Comment: Are the names unique?

Comment: `pd.NA` can not be correctly compared  (either elementwise or rowwise) as it throws `TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with indicator:

```
keep = (
 df.merge(pd.DataFrame(to_delete, columns=df.columns), how='left', indicator=True)
   .query('_merge == "left_only"').index
)

out = df.loc[keep]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
      name stuff floats  ints
1     Joey     d    2.2     3
2  Zendaya     c   <NA>     8
3     John     a    1.0     1
```

Comment: thanks for this merge property instructive example

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the drop function to delete rows and columns in a Pandas DataFrame.**

You can use the following code for your help finding the row and delete.

```
import pandas as pa

res = pa.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Mike', 'Joey', 'Zendaya', 'John', 'Abruzzi'],
    'stuff': ['a', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'd'],
    'floats': [1.0, 2.2, pa.NA, 1.0, pa.NA],
    'ints': [1, 3, 8, 1, 3]
})

remove = [['Abruzzi', 'd', pa.NA, 3], ['Mike', 'a', 1.0, 1]]

res = res[~res.isin(remove)].dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: This doesn't work